# Como passar argumentos para um script PHP via linha de comando?

Tags: php, terminal

Tenho um script **PHP** que recebe argumentos da seguinte maneira: `script.php -f "valor"`.

- Como faço para o PHP passar esse argumento via linha de comando?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para pegar os nomes e valores dos argumentos pela linha de comando utilize [$argv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

linha de comando:

```
 php cmd.php -p1 v1 -p2 v2
```

**cmd.php**

```
print_r($argv);
```

Sendo que o primeiro item de `$argv` é o nome do script. A saida de cmd.php será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cmd.php
    [1] => -p1
    [2] => v1
    [3] => -p2
    [4] => v2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode está utilizando da função [`getopt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getopt.php) que nada mais é que uma abreviação de *"Get Options"*.

```php
<?php  

    $args = getopt('f:'); // refere-se ao parâmetro "-f"
    print_r($args); // será imprimida e seu retorno será um Array

?>
```

essa função vai retornar uma matriz de opções/argumentos no Prompt de Comando (*ou em qualquer outra shell/console*)

> php script.php -f "ola mundo"

```
Array
(
    [f] => ola mundo
)
```

#### O contrário do `$argv`

```
<?php  
    
    print_r($argv); // obtêm quaisquer argumentos passados (incluindo o próprio arquivo)

?>
```

> php script.php teste1 teste2 teste3

```
Array
(
    [0] => script.php
    [1] => teste1
    [2] => teste2
    [3] => teste3
)
```

---

#### Eu sugiro que

faça o uso do `getopt()` pois com ele você pode pré-definir parâmetros específicos, fazendo com que ele **não** retorne qualquer argumento "fora do normal" (*Ele obtêm o que você quer que ele obtenha!*). Tendo assim um controle do conteúdo da `Array` gerada.

> Vale ressaltar alguns pontos em que deve-se respeitar parâmetros, como já diz o nome!
> como por exemplo o uso do "-f", onde a ser passado "-ff" como parâmetro
> `php script.php -ff "ola mundo"`

seu resultado será um "f" como valor e não o que foi passado após ele.

```
Array 
(
    [f] => f
)
```

Comment: [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas)