# Como fazer o PHP ler a entrada na linha de comando como string?

Tags: php, linha-de-comando

No `Python`, sei que para ler os dados inseridos pela linha de comando utilizamos a função `raw_input`.

Exemplo:

Script Python:

```
print 'digite algo para inicializar'

resultado = raw_input()

print 'O resultado é ' + resultado
```

Linha de comando:

```
> python script.py
digite algo para inicializar
> teste
o resultado é teste
```

E no PHP? Como fazer o PHP ler a entrada na linha de comando?

**Observação**: Quero capturar a entrada não na inicialização do script, mas "no meio" dele, como no exemplo do `python`, demonstrado acima.

Comment: Isso [Como passar argumentos para um script PHP via linha de comando?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10602/91) ?

Comment: @rray, nesse caso os valores são passados inicialmente ao script. Queria saber como faço para fazer isso quando o script já foi inicializado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito através da função `fgets` combinado com a constante `STDIN`.

Veja:

```
$line = fgets(STDIN);
```

Script PHP

```
echo "iniciando a aplicação php\n";

$line = fgets(STDIN);

echo "O resultado é '{$line}'";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja a resposta tirada do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543936/3096922)

Apesar de `fgets` ser utilizado na maioria dos casos para ler ponteiro de arquivos, o PHP aceita suporte a protocolos e wrappers, através dessas funções.

Nesse caso, estamos lendo a entrada da linha de comando como se fosse uma linha de um arquivo.

Veja o código funcionando no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/K3eG7X)

Comment: A função fgets não funciona para entradas em linha de comando.

Comment: Acho que você não testou o código, pois pra mim funcionou corretamente.

Comment: A sua própria resposta prova que o `fgets` funciona. Talvez você não tenha visto [isso](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.php#94924) na página onde você linkou na sua resposta

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu acho que o que eles queriam dizer com "pela linha de comandos" era, pex, isto: `php cmd.php arg1 arg2 arg3` no entanto, não é isso que o user quer (ou pelo menos, não foi o que entendi) e a tua resposta está awesomesauce :)

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Awesomesauce

Comment: Não tiro a qualidade do método `fgets`, também acho ele ótimo para utilizar em uma pergunta no PHP, mas a questão é como fazer isso via linha de comando, se você souber a resposta, eu te dou todo meu apoio. Não estou aqui para desqualificar, só para contribuir.

Answer (score 2):

Para entrada de dados no php utilize o "argv": `$argv[0]`.

Segue um exemplo para a entrada de um único parâmetro:

```
<?php

if ($argc != 2 || in_array($argv[1], array('texto1', 'texto 2', 'texto3', 'texto4'))) {
     echo $argv[0]; 
} else {
     echo $argv[1];
}

 ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.argv.php

Aqui tem mais detalhes sobre linha de comando:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.php

E aqui tem alguns exemplos de utilização: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048835/php-pass-parameters-from-command-line-to-a-php-script

Comment: -1. Essa abordagem é utilizada para parâmetros passados na inicialização do script. No caso, estamos falando da leitura que ocorre com o script já inicializado.

Comment: Entradas argv podem ser usadas em qualquer estágio do script. Ela é uma variável de array reservada para `inputs`.

Comment: _Observação: Quero capturar a entrada não na inicialização do script, mas "no meio" dele, como no exemplo do python, demonstrado acima._

Comment: Como disse, ela pode ser usada em qualquer estágio... ela independe do método para recerber entradas.

Comment: Ivan, eu alterei a pergunta, já que aparentemente não ficou claro o que eu queria. Eu sei que o `$argv` pode ser utilizado, mas são parâmetros passados para a execução do script. Ele não "pega" os valores capturados como entradas (como no caso de um "Deseja deletar os arquivos?[y|n]". Quero que essa captura ocorra depois que o script é inicializado, e não passagem de parâmetros.